# Body-background-position:center doesn't work i. explorer

Tags: html, css, browser

I am making a web site and I have trouble with background-position property. Here is my css code:

body

{

```
background-color: Black;

background-image: url(images/background_ui.png);

background-repeat: no-repeat;

background-position: top,center;

background-attachment: scroll;
```

}

As you can see it is top, center. It's ok in chrome but in ie 8 the background doesnt go center horizontally. By the way, do you know any tags to write browser specified css code?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that comma is correct.., it should be: `background position: top center`

Comment: If you don't mind, I 'll answer properly and you can accept it as the correct answer for any other users that might have the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that comma is correct.., it should be: `background position: top center`. Generally speaking, CSS compound rules like `background-position` or `background` do not have their values separated with commas. Instead, they get separated with one or more spaces. Your CSS from above, for instance can become like this:

```
background: black url(images/background_ui.png) no-repeat scroll top center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax might not be right.

The position should be either top or center. The fact it works on chrome and not in IE is because by default chromse seems to center it.

I think this might help you:

```
{
background-position-x: 50%; 
background-position-y: 0%; 
}
```

EDIT:  Ioannis Karadimas is also right. Losing the comma is going to give you your desired effect. Though i'd still use the xy placement to avoid having cross browser surprises.

Comment: It says "background-position-x" is not a known css property. .But the Karadimas' answer works.